# How do I restore modified firmware to a read only mount

Tags: disassembly, linux, embedded

I have managed to get a root shell on my web filtering router by plugging into a UART on the PCB which allowed me to see a process (lockbox.bin - ELF executable) running which handles most of the filtering functions. After extracting the lockbox.bin file and analyzing it with IDA pro, I've made some modifications to the file. I now need to get it back on the device to see if the changes worked, but when I try to make changes to the filesystem I get a message saying that the file system is read only. I suppose it's only a matter of mounting the filesystem as read/write, but I'm not sure how to do that (Access the boot loader?). The Busybox instance on the device is missing the mount command. The router in question is a re-branded realtek rtl8196b.

Any Suggestions?

Disclaimer: This is the first time that I've have done something like this so I may be missing a very basic step. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very probable that the firmware is stored in a `squashfs` image, which is compressed (and supposed to be read-only - it can't be mouted read-write, but must be created through external means), The squashfs image will probably be stored in some piece of flash ram, which can be accessed as `/dev/mtbn` on many linux embedded devices, which multiple values of `n` refering to different parts of the firmware (boot loader etc.).

Often, the boot loader itself is in `/dev/mtb0`, and has commands to write to the other `/dev/mtb` blocks.

So, your course of action would be

- dump the various `/dev/mtb` blocks to files, check which is a squashfs, or maybe different type of file system, that contains your lockbox.bin
- rebuild that filesystem with your different version of lockbox.bin, and hope it doesn't grow significantly larger to exceed the size of the `/dev/mtb` block
- check how to boot to the boot loader from outside, without starting linux
- use some boot loader to flash that filesystem to the router
- reboot the router, and hope you didn't brick it in the process.

As you say

> This is the first time that I've have done something like this

the chance of

> brick it in the process.

is certainly non-zero, so proceed with caution.

Comment: Thanks for the information and Advice. Step 1: I did that and found the file system under /dev/mtd. I has a squashFS files sytem (also under the device as /dev/mtdblock1) Step 2: Do you just rebuild the file system using the directory structure of the host that you are working on? Step 3: Any suggestions on where to start looking? Step 4: Same. Once again, thanks for your help.